# Grammar structure for "which do you like more?" questions

Tags: grammar, mandarin

[This page](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Basic_comparisons_with_%22bi%22) explains how to state simple comparisons, but doesn't address how to ask about more complex comparisons.

For instance, what's the right Mandarin equivalent of the English question structure: "Do you like A more than B?"

1) Do you like Chinese food more than Japanese food?

2) Do you like planes more than trains?

How do you deal with the verb?

Do you duplicate it like this: 妳喜歡中國菜比喜歡日本菜多嗎？

Is there a "cleaner", more concise grammatical form where you don't duplicate the verb? For instance, could you do this: 妳喜歡中國菜比日本菜多嗎？

Comment: 妳更喜歡中國菜還是日本菜？Do you prefer Chinese cuisine to Japanese cuisine? 中國菜和日本菜妳更喜歡哪個？Which one do you like more, Chinese cuisine or Japanese cuisine? 比起中國菜你更喜歡日本菜嗎？Compare to Chinese cuisine, do you prefer Japanese cuisine? 妳喜歡中國菜勝過日本菜嗎？Do you like Chinese cuisine more than Japanese cuisine?

Comment: You asked the same question four months ago and you marked a correct answer with follow up questions.

Comment: @user3306356 thank you for catching this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammar structure for [like A more than B]

> 1. insert "多過" (more than) between object A and object B:
>
> [妳喜歡中國菜][**多過**][日本菜] = [you like Chinese food] [**more than** ][Japanese food]

*I think it is the "cleanest" grammar structure you are looking for, to express "[(verb)(object A) (more than) (object B)]"*

*The verb act on both object A  and object B.  Therefore, we don't need to repeat the verb for object B. As in "[妳喜歡中國菜][**多過**][(喜歡  )日本菜]"*

~

> 2. Topic and opinion structure:
>
> [**Compare to** object B] as a topic
>
> [like object A **more**] as the opinion
>
> [**比起**日本菜], [我][**更**喜歡中國菜]= [**compare to**  Japanese food] [I] [like Chinese food **more**]

*更 short for 更為. You can replace 更 with 較, which in term is short for 較為*

Answer (score 2):

Here are some very clean ways to express this:

- 你喜欢[...]，还是[...]
- 你更喜欢[...]，还是[...]
- [...]好，还是[...]好

Answer (score 2):

'like' is very subjective, so can be replaced with 'think, feel'.

你觉得日料更好，还是中餐更好吗？
Do you think Japanese food is best, or Chinese food?

你觉得中餐比日料更好吗？
Do you think Chinese food is better than Japanese food?

I don't think you really mean 'like planes' but 'like to travel in planes'

你觉得乘飞机更好，还是乘火车更好？
Do you like to travel in planes or trains more?